# How to give space from origin in overlapping bar graph Highcarts

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I have created an overlapping bar graph of Highcharts but in the first bar it is not displaying the full bar....half of the graph is showing.

Could any body give me any suggestion to show the first bar as others coming.

Thanks,
Ashraf

Comment: show your code as well, only graph is not sufficient, and which graph type is this? Fixed placement columns?

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its working fine in Jsfiddle but I can't find why it is not coming in aspx page...here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ashraf1989/9o1faaex/

Comment: Maybe (asp) wrapper which you use for highcharts is not up-to-date.